# Which one is gramatically correct

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, past-tense

Actually, I am writing a story. I have to explain the poverty of a family. So please let me know  which one is the grammatically correct and reasons behind them, in the following two statements.

> - There wasn't any question of them being able to buy a better house — or
>     even one more bed to sleep in. They were far too poor for that.
> - As they were far poor,they were unable to buy a better house and even one more bed to sleep in.

Comment: Both are just fine, grammatically speaking, except for a couple minor errors in the 2nd sentence. In terms of *style*, the first reads as much more *literate* (in the voice of a narrator), and the second more *journalistic* (in the voice of a reporter). My preference is for the former, it makes better, more vivid, use of language. The latter is a bit flat (and the language is a bit simple). BTW, in the second example, you want to say "*far **too** poor*", and use "***or** even one more bed", instead of "***and** even one more bed*".

Comment: Oh, but there is a much bigger issue here. The first sentence is quoted verbatim from Charlie and the Chocolate factory, which means it would be outright ***plagiarism*** to include it in your story without attribution to Roald Dahl. Please don't do that.

Comment: @DanBron I am getting confusion while using the first one.Because, in general I use 'being able to' with be form. For example, I was not being able to buy a car. But here I could not find such be form. So please help me to get out of this.

Comment: yes, I noticed.

Comment: Native speakers of American English and British English make much less use of the present progressive ("*being able to*") than Indian speakers who learned English as a second language. Which is to say, if you're trying to write the story in idiomatic English, it's better to avoid constructions like "*I was not being able to buy a car*". With that said, it's your story, do whatever you like! You asked for opinions, so I'm only providing my own. Good luck!

Comment: @DanBron -thanks, then in that case, could you tell me how can I express "I was not being able to buy a car" as a native speaker, please?

Comment: @paramod, we'd either say "*I **couldn't** buy a car*" or, in more formal contexts, sometimes "*I **wasn't able** to buy a car*". We'd be much more likely to use the latter when focusing on the obstacles to purchase, and likely in a scenario where we're trying to purchase a *specific* car, meaning we'd likely use the  "*wasn't able*"' formulation in conjunction with the definite article "***the** car*".

Comment: @DanBron So the first construction is in present progressive, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18040/discussion-between-pramod-and-dan-bron).

Comment: I've told you what I can. Good luck with your story (and please remember to properly attribute any material you include from other authors, plagiarism can lead to real trouble!).

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct. The second sentence should be written as:

> As they were far **too** poor, they were unable to buy a better house, **or** even one more bed to sleep in.

Answer (score -1):

You could write:

- There wasn't any question of them being able to buy a better house; they couldn't even afford another bed.

Why? a dash/hyphen isn't typically used before or, connectives already provide structure in a sentence. Here, a semi-colon is used as the fact they couldn't use is a separate clause (i,e they would both be OK sentences on there own)
or:

- As they were too poor, they were unable to buy a better house; they couldn't afford an extra bed.

Why? Same sort of reasoning to the sentence above, two independent clauses.

You used the word "far" to describe the scale of the problem you could use "far too" or "too". If you are too poor to buy a house, then does it really matter the scale of the problem? "far too" although not grammatically incorrect sounds very "chatty". However,this is personal preference.

Comment: can you explain how many ways can we use the "being able to " phrase ?

Comment: That dash is perfectly acceptable in context. It signals a kind of *afterthought*.

Comment: I am voting this answer down because it reflects a lack of understanding of the idiomatic locution "much|far too" in "far too poor": *If you are too poor to buy a house, then does it really matter the scale of the problem?* It means the family had so little money that buying a house was completely out of the question. They were not a family who might be able to buy a house if they were a little more frugal in their spending habits, say.

Comment: @pramod "being able to" means "to allow"